# Como compartilhar um webservice através de um FTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-service

#### Contextualização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# para acessar um webservice teste que criei. Este webservice é simples, só possui um método que retorna uma string.

O webservice eu criei pelo Visual Studio, através de um projeto Asp.net. Adicionei um webservice no projeto e implementei o método que retorna uma string.

#### Projeto ASP.Net

***Estrutura do projeto***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Arquivos gerados pelo projeto***

Na pasta do projeto Asp.net, foram gerados os arquivos conforme print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo destacado (testeWS) está no formato .asmx.

***Método do webservice***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Projeto executado pelo Visual Studio***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que o método (testandoRetornoWebService) aparece no início da página.

Após eu clicar no link do método, aparece a seguinte página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clico no botão chamar desta página, recebo a mensagem que o método testandoRetornoWebService retorna, que é "WebService funcionando corretamente".

#### O problema

Eu coloquei o arquivo "testeWS.asmx" na pasta WebService do meu FTP para tentar requisitá-lo via browser. Entratanto, não estou conseguindo.

Estou na dúvidade se preciso compartilhar todos os arquivos do projeto Asp.net que criei ou se preciso fazer uma coisa completamente diferente.

Segue a print de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após inserir, no arquivo Web.Config, a tag que habilita a exibição da mensagem de erro, obtive a seguinte página ao tentar requisitar o arquivo "testeWS.asmx" pelo browser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Código do Web.config***

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/><customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

#### Web FTP

Os arquivos que gerei ao publicar o projeto em ASP.Net estão da seguinte forma no FTP:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz o upload de todos os arquivos gerados no processo de publicação do projeto ASP.Net pelo Visual Studio.

Comment: Aparece algum erro? Tenta compartilhar todos os arquivos que compõe a aplicação.

Comment: Simplesmente colocar um arquivo no seu FTP não vai funcionar. Você vai precisar gerar o "Publish" dos arquivos, provavelmente configurar seu IIS no servidor FTP e ai sim colocar os arquivos do "Publish" lá.

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha eu publiquei o projeto em uma pasta do meu computador e enviei todos os arquivos para uma pasta do meu FTP. Mesmo fazendo desta forma, o erro persiste.

Comment: @HudsonRodrigues como local funcionou, o que pode ser é que há um erro de configuração do servidor. Tente, temporariamente, ativar nas configurações do Web.config para mostrar o erro que esta dando. Na mensagem ao carregar a página mostra como fazer isso

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha editei o post com a nova tela de erro. configurei o arquivo Web.config para exibir a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @HudsonRodrigues parece que agora é outro problema, verifica se no arquivo Web.config existe mais de um `<customErrors mode="Off"/><customErrors mode="Off"/>`

Comment: @LeandroAmarilha só tem o que eu adicionei.

Comment: Além do arquivo `asmx` você precisa de todos os arquivos dentro da pasta `bin`. Além disso, este webservice está na pasta **root** do servidor web?

Comment: @jbueno atualizei o post com os arquivos que coloquei no FTP. Eles são os mesmos arquivos que foram gerados na publicação do projeto no Visual Studio.

Comment: Acontece que você precisa criar um diretório virtual na sua hospedagem

Comment: @jbueno como eu faria isso? Poderia ser mais específico, obrigado.

Comment: Não tem como ser mais específico. Você precisa criar um diretório virtual para sua aplicação, é assim que o IIS funciona. Eu não tenho como mostrar isso usando prints porque não uso os serviços da Kinghost.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa publicar seu webservice e configurar o IIS para que tenha acesso a ele.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/8wbhsy70(v=vs.100).aspx